# expand and collapse multiple divs/tables in a page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I was able to collapse all the divs on page load but to expand a table on click of a particular div. 
One simple way of doing it is assign unique id's to each table and on click of the div pass the table id to javascript function and set the style to display.

I wanted to know if there is any other method because I need to implement this across several pages.Any other simpler solution would help.

I need help to write code in javascript not jquery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why the downvote was there. It seems a legitimate question, asking how to make an element disappear and reappear.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to set the `element.style.display` property to `none`. When you need the element to reappear again, you can set the property back to what it was before. This way, your code is not dependant on a CSS rule, and other rules that may apply to that ID won't interfere with yours.

```
//to disappear (example for a div)
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'none';
//to reappear
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'block';
```

Keep in mind that some elements have different default values. For instance, `div` has a display of `block`, but `img` by default has a display of `inline`.

---

EDIT:

In case I misread your question, another way would be to add the class name `disappear` to your element. In your CSS doc:

```
.dissapear {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, when you need it to disappear, just remove the class from the element.

Comment: Thank you MineandCraft12 for the detailed explanation. This is what I tried but I was looking if there is a more efficient approach than this.Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: I believe these would be some of the more efficient ways to go - judging that each method needs only one line of code to turn on and off - but it is possible that there's another out there. In a rush at the moment, I can't look, but soon as I get a chance, I'm going to look further into  it.

Comment: Thanks MineAndCrafy12